# Quick capture of www URLs to local LIFO stack of hyperlinks?

Tags: bookmarks

I often come across interesting websites while looking for something else, and I want to be able to quickly "push" (i.e. capture) their URLs onto a consolidated *stack* of clickable links, in ***LIFO*** order, for review at a later time.  (It would be great if it were easy to "pop" links from this stack, but this is gravy.)

My current method for capturing URLs is awfully inconvenient: I choose my browser's "share" option, and email the URL to myself.  This is not only slow and cumbersome, but the captured URLs get spread over a bazillion separate email messages.

In fact, the absence of a consolidated "dumping site" for these captured URLs is the weakness of every info capture app I've tried so far: quick capture always results in one link per "node" (or email message, or "note", or whatever) in a way that makes it difficult to review the current LIFO stack of URLs.  With some of them it *may* be possible to simulate the "LIFO stack" effect, but this is invariably at the expense of speed and ease of capture.

Another feature of many of these apps that I found highly undesirable is that they stored the information remotely.  I *definitely* want to keep this information ***exclusively local***, i.e. in my phone.  I ***don't*** want to find myself in the near future bumping into a "free storage limit" at some remote site (as with, e.g. Evernote).

Does anyone know an app that meets these criteria?

Comment: Just Google'd "LIFO" and apparently it stands for "Last In First Out". It might have helped things more if you'd explained what that meant and that one of your core requirements was for an unusual ordering, instead of putting up a huge, barely readable ASCII art banner (that looks like it says "LOOOL UFO")

Comment: @GAThrawn: Are you telling me that you *did not even **understand** what the question asking, and answered anyway???*  And on top of that all that you are putting the blame on me???  That's rich.

Comment: @kjo He has answered after Googling.. And, he is right: LIFO might be Greek for many.. you should elaborate it for clarification.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: No, you got the timeline wrong.  He/she Googled only after I posted comments about the absence of any indication that the answers addressed the original question.  As to your second point, if someone asks a question about X, why would he/she want to get answers from those ***who don't even know what X is?***  I, for one, am not interested in those answers.  In any case, I think it is perfectly reasonable for the asker to expect that those who don't even know what the question is asking about would have the common sense, if not the elementary courtesy, not to answer it.

Comment: @kjo What if someone knows about X in another way? Here, my target is your way.. Its definitely not wise ask `What's the boiling temperature of Hydrogen Dioxide?` instead of `What's the boiling temperature of Water?`... In this example, you can see how an easy question becomes difficult for many. Would you say, those who doesn't know what hydrogen dioxide is, can't tell boiling temperature of Water?

Comment: It's your choice how you ask your questions.  I told you what my choice is for mine: I prefer to see the answers coming from people who know the terminology I use, and *exclude* answers from those who don't know this terminology.  I think the benefits of this preference outweigh its drawbacks.  I can't go into what these are, sorry.  I don't understand your insistence on browbeating me into adopting your viewpoint.  Sorry, but you don't have a case: it all boils down to personal preference.  Ask your questions however you like, and let me ask mine however I like, ok?

Answer (score 5):

I just stumbled upon [Pocket -formerly Read It Later](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideashower.readitlater.pro). Might be worth a try.

Comment: It looks like I may have up-voted this reply prematurely...  I could not find anything saying that bookmarks are stored in LIFO order.  Are they?  Also, it looks like there's no way to keep the bookmarks exclusively local to my device.  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Install [Clipper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rojekti.clipper) and start copying your URLs in clipboard.

It creates LIFO stack from clipboard and is exclusively local. To revisit URLs, bring this lightweight app from status bar.. tap URL to copy and paste in address bar. Done!

Free version of Clipper limits user to 20 items in stack. If you don't want to purchase its pro version, you can use [aNdClip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazing_create.android.andclipfree). But, you may face problems in keeping LIFO structure after copying an URL from stack.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to more literally do what you're asking is to get a browser that supports tabs (for example, Google Chrome for Android, Dolphin Browser, or even the built in one) and open a new tab for each interesting link.  Then you'll literaly have the stack you're looking for.  The cool thing about Google Chrome is that this stack will be persistant across reboots and accessible across devices.

Anyways, hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, but I think there is limitation on number of tabs. Do you know about it?

Comment: At least in Google Chrome for Android, I just opened 100 tabs and there's no evidence it cares.  Especially if you're going to be using it as a LIFO, I have my doubts you'd let it get up to 100 tabs, though.

Comment: There's certainly a *practical* limitation: try creating a dozen tabs by right-clicking on YouTube links (for example).  Many websites are very resource-hungry (JavaScript, AJAX, Flash, you name it).  This precludes browser tab creation (which amounts to "website visiting") as a strategy.

Comment: @kjo I doubt it keeps all 100 tabs loaded at the same time, though I could be wrong.  Did you try it?

Comment: @kjo web browsers unloads inactive tab content from memory in case of memory unavailablity.. So, that's just like bookmark..

Comment: @SachinShekhar: not in my experience.  I routinely render my Chrome session unusable because of too many tabs.  Granted, this is very sensitive to what's on those tabs.  Try this: go to YouTube and right-click-open a dozen different videos into separate tabs.  At the very least I expect that you will have to visit each of these tabs to stop the videos, or mute your sound, or endure the cacophony of 12 soundtracks playing simultaneously.  At least this is what I experience when I do something like this.  And...

Comment: ...my browser becomes as slow as molasses.  A very different experience from "just like bookmarking".

Comment: @kjo there's need of BarTab alternative, then.. :)

Comment: BTW, my Dolphin does a nice job in this aspect, but yes.. its more than bookmark.. :)